# What is a good framework for Database Migrations that is compatibile with SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, schema, migration, revision

I've been spoiled by ActiveRecords.  So I'm on the lookout for migration system that can be applied to SQL Server, and either is executed as Java application, or a Win32 Executable.  (Of course further compatibility with other DB's and host OS's is welcome.)

The real desire is having a clear schema change application with roll back, ideally in something nicer then SQL so it can be DB system agnostic.

The hitch I've found for alternatives that are Java based, is lack of clean support for the Microsoft JDBC.

Looking forward to any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Ben Sheirmans excellent post on the topic:

http://flux88.com/blog/net-database-migration-tool-roundup/

I tried Tarantino and it worked OK, but you're still locked to sql scripts for sql server.

/Anders

Answer (score 0):

Try Mite.  I wrote it and have been using it for years successfully.

https://github.com/soitgoes/mite

If you turn on "Auto Generate Change Scripts" then Sql Management Studio will generate the sql that you can save into your mite file.  No more writing migrations just let Management Studio do it for you!  Then if you ever need to custom craft something to alter data you can simply do that in sql and save it to a migration.

[image]

Let me know what you think.